# How can I restart apache 2.2.9?

Tags: apache-2.2

What is the command to restart Apache 2.2.9?

Comment: better still, do you get a way to manage Apache - that is like the IIS7 snapin?

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question regarding Apache Management.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux? Why are you restarting? You need to be more specific and provide more details when you ask questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically

```
apache2ctl restart
```

does a complete restart (shut it down and start it up again), or

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

does a "graceful restart" which waits for any existing connections to close before restarting.  But it could depend on which operating system you're using. On mine (Gentoo Linux) the preferred way is

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

May be different if Apacxhe is installed with a different path but:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/apachectl restart
```

or look for a boot script like:

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd stop
$ /etc/init.d/http start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the redhat family of distros (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, etc) the proper way is

> /sbin/service httpd restart

a lot of times you can get away with

> /sbin/service httpd graceful